# PHP cURL cannot fetch read a page

Tags: php, curl

Tried to read URL below by using PHP cURL, but it just returned empty. How to read the URL below using cURL in PHP?

URL: https://www.wingyipstore.co.uk/sauces-pastes/stir-fry-sauces

```
$curl = curl_init();

$header = array(
        "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Connection:keep-alive",
        "Host:www.wingyipstore.co.uk",
        "Origin:http://www.wingyipstore.co.uk/",
        "Referer:http://www.wingyipstore.co.uk/sauces-pastes/stir-fry-sauces",
        "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"
     );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 " );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to anything other than `0`?

Comment: yes, tried, no difference. the scripts above works well with other URLs.

Comment: if you `var_dump($data);`, is it an empty string or `false`? If it's `false`, an error occurred. You could try `echo curl_error($curl)`; before calling `curl_close()` to see what (if anything) is going wrong.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. if I var_dump($data); I got "bool(false)
"; and when add echo curl_errror, I got error: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure;

Comment: Looks like this exact error: https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=534, try their solution and let us know if it works

Comment: thank you, rickdenhaan! new error; error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake

Comment: Apparently, some servers don't allow `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` `3` due to the POODLE vulnerability. Try a higher number (up to 6).